# Stop the docker container when docker host reboot and restart the docker container only when container crashed due to error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

Scenario :
Stop the docker container when docker host reboot and restart the docker container only when container crashed due to error.

None of the existing restart_policy works for me for above scenario?

Comment: Is this not covering your request ? 

`unless-stopped : Similar to always, except that when the container is stopped (manually or otherwise), it is not restarted even after Docker daemon restarts.`

Comment: No. I want to achieve two things in my docker. 1. all running containers need to be stopped on host reboot  2. Restart the containers if it crashed with some error